# Do pyspark collect_list() and collect_set() use groupByKey or do they use reduceByKey?

Tags: pyspark, group-by

I came across two built-in aggregation methods for pyspark dataframes, `collect_list` and `collect_set`. I want to know how they perform the aggregation. Do they use `groupByKey` behind the scenes (which requires data-shuffling first and hence slower) or do they use `reduceByKey` behind the scenes (which does not require data-shuffling first and hence faster)?

Comment: From my understanding, these two functions should be used within a groupby. The groupby implies a shuffle. Then, the aggregation itself should be a simple map. Spark code is available online, you can check how the functions are defined.

Comment: @Steven Yes groupby implies shuffling but when we call groupby and then aggregate using some built-in function like `count` or `sum`, then initially data is not shuffled. Pyspark first does the aggregation or row-reduction locally in each machine, then shuffles the data. But, another way of aggregation would be to shuffle the data first and then perform the aggregation. I want to know which of these 2 ways does `collect_list` or `collect_set` follow.